# Disable Dialog closing after ENTER button pressed in ControlsFX

Tags: dialog, javafx, enter

I have extended `org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog` and added some TextField to it, which is supposed to act when `ENTER` button is pressed (if TextField has focus). However when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, my dialog takes over of steering, and act like on `OK` button was pressed.

Is there any method which I can override in order to change this behavior (to intercept `Enter` action)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask on ControlsFX mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/controlsfx-dev

Answer (score 1):

I have received some workaround to this problem at ControlsFX mailing list which is good for me. To disable `Dialog` closing  after `Enter` button is pressed in `TextField` we must consume event in `EventHandler` attached to this `TextField`

```
    textField.addEventFilter(new EventHandler() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent evt) {
           .......
           evt.consume();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works this:

```java
dialog.getDialogPane().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```